# sqlite database update

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am using the following code for updating an entry in my table in sqlite. not interferring with the other columns just have to edit the balance one. But its giving me no change in the database.Can someone help me out here..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];

sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
    const char *sql = "update Account Set currentBalance = ? Where ID = ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 1, 1000);

sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2 , 1);
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);


sqlite3_close(database);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO this...

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];
//NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "update Account Set currentBalance = ? Where ID = ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 1, 1000);

sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2 , 1);


char* errmsg;
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);


sqlite3_close(database);
```